# Integration by parts, natural logarithm

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

I am having A LOT of problems with this one equation, could anyone help me? I know the answer, I just don't understand how to get there.

$$\int x^3 e^{x^2} dx$$

There's the equation, and the answer is: 
$$\int e^{x^2} x^3 dx = \frac 1 2 e^{x^2} (x^2 - 1) + \text{ constant} $$

I keep trying using the usual integration by parts method but I just can't get there no matter what. I use 
$$\int u dv = uv - \int v du.$$ but I seem to never get it right.

Comment: Hint: if you know the answer then you can "reverse engineer" it to find the solution method.  To differentiate the answer you would probably use first the product rule and then the chain rule.  So to do the integral you would "reverse" this: first substitution, then integration by parts.

Answer (score 3):

Use the substitution $x^2=t \Rightarrow 2x\,dx=dt$ to get:
$$\int x^3e^{x^2}\,dx=\frac{1}{2}\int te^t \,dt$$
The last integral can be evaluated using integration by parts:
$$\frac{1}{2}\int te^t \,dt=\frac{1}{2}\left(te^t-e^t\right)+C=\frac{1}{2}e^t(t-1)+C$$
Since $t=x^2$, 
$$\frac{1}{2}e^t(t-1)+C=\boxed{\dfrac{1}{2}e^{x^2}(x^2-1)+C}$$

Comment: What about $+c$?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese gotta leave something for the OP to do ;-)

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese: Woops, I forgot, thanks for the reminder! :D

Answer (score 1):

Let $u=x^2$ and $dv=xe^{x^2}\,dx$. Then $du=2x\,dx$ and $v$ can be taken to be $\frac{1}{2}e^{x^2}$. So we arrive at
$$\frac{1}{2}x^2e^{x^2} -\int xe^{x^2}\,dx.$$
This last integral is straightforward, indeed has already been done.

**Remark:** Even though integration by parts works directly, the preliminary substitution $t=x^2$, as in the solution by Pranav Arora, is a better way to proceed.